# Issue with innerWidth not matching screen dimensions; MediaQueries

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was playing around with Media Queries and practicing Mobile-First design, however I'm running into an issue when trying to revert back to a Mobile screen. I discovered the issue is that my page's innerwidth is always ~980, even if I set the device width to <469 in the developer console.

At first thought it was syntax with my viewport or media queries but I can't seem to figure out that item that's causing the grief. The Media Query for max of 468 was my last ditch effort to make this work but It'll never actually trigger since my page can at minimum be 980px according to the innerWidth.

Any and all help/suggestions appreciated:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HEAD>
<meta type="viewport" content="width:device-width, initial-scale:1.0">
<style>
    .title {
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: cornflowerblue;
    }
    
    .navBar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: slategray;
    }

    .navBar a {
        width: 33%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 100px;
        font-size: 35px;
        color:violet;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 100px;
    }

    .title p {
        font-size: 58px;
        color:red;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 100px;
    }

    .content {
        width: 95%;
        height: 1200px;
        margin-left: 2.5%;
        margin-right: 2.5%;
    }

    .subTitle {
        font-size: 24px;
        color: black;
        float: left;
    }

    .textBlock {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        clear: both;
        font-size: 32px;
        text-align: justify;        
    }

    .adSpace {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .content img {
        width: 100%;
    }

    @media (max-width: 468px) {
        .adSpace {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: 1151px) and (min-width: 469px) {
        .content {
            float: left;
            width: 75%;
        }
        
        .adSpace { 
            width: 20%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(222, 184, 135, 0.52);
            float: right;
            visibility: visible;
        }

        .ad {
            width: 95%;
            margin-left: 2.5%;
            margin-right: 2.5%;
            margin-top: 5px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: darkgreen;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1152px) {
        .navBar {
            width: 20%;
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
        }
        
        .navBar a {
            clear:both;
            width: 100%;
            height: 125px;
        }

        .content {
            float: left;
            width: 55%;
        }

        .adSpace {
            visibility: visible;
        }

        .adSpace { 
            width: 20%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(222, 184, 135, 0.52);
            float: right;
            visibility: visible;
        }

        .ad {
            width: 95%;
            margin-left: 2.5%;
            margin-right: 2.5%;
            margin-top: 5px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: darkgreen;
        }
    }
</style>
</HEAD>
<body style="background-color: silver;">
<div class="title">
    <p>Responsive Web: Mobile First Design</p>
</div>
<div class="navBar">
    <a href="google.ca">Google</a>
    <a href="youtube.com">Youtube</a>
    <a href="w3schools.com">W3Schools</a>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="picture">
        <img src="5igniataegu21.png"/>
    </div>
    <div class="subTitle">
        <p>By: Mitchell Boutilier; Nov 10th, 2021</p>
    </div>
    <div class="textBlock">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In nibh ante, laoreet et felis placerat, bibendum aliquet ante. Mauris 
            eget lorem volutpat, tristique tellus vel, congue sem. Vestibulum tincidunt nulla vel tortor vulputate, non porttitor justo 
            auctor. Cras aliquet, arcu at tincidunt efficitur, lorem nisl tincidunt felis, in iaculis ipsum erat sed orci. Phasellus enim 
            lectus, scelerisque eget aliquam at, pretium non urna. Nullam eu mauris ex. Fusce nec finibus odio. Mauris vehicula bibendum 
            ante eu pretium. Vivamus ornare odio ut mi fermentum scelerisque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et 
            ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Aliquam varius lacus sit amet magna ultrices pharetra. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis 
            dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus sed nunc nisl. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus 
            et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In tempor augue sed ante sagittis suscipit.

            In scelerisque convallis semper. Nullam commodo eu tellus ac imperdiet. Duis in feugiat est. Aenean non molestie leo, quis 
            sagittis ipsum. Fusce vel mauris venenatis tellus vehicula condimentum eu in urna. Suspendisse ut mollis augue. Duis ac 
            consequat nulla, id suscipit nunc. Curabitur mollis enim sit amet dolor cursus, in mattis velit auctor. In tortor ex, 
            pharetra a convallis interdum, fermentum sed urna. Nullam quis dui urna. Integer egestas, nisl id sagittis tincidunt, 
            lorem ex posuere dui, non dictum felis lectus ac ante. Morbi quis euismod massa, in posuere erat. Integer id enim et 
            diam condimentum bibendum non sit amet lorem.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="adSpace">
    <div class="ad"></div>
    <div class="ad"></div>
    <div class="ad"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you know the difference between hardware pixels (physical pixels) and software-pixels (css-pixel): https://juiceboxinteractive.com/blog/a-pixel-is-not-a-pixel-designing-for-a-new-generation-of-mobile-devices/? Also you should test with actual devices not with the browsers dev-tools

Comment: @tacoshy I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to point at with that article, as it's being device specific and going way beyond the scope of what I'm doing. I'm just trying to do a generic mobile/tablet/desktop setup. And I don't have devices to test on, this is a basic html document I load in a browser, not a site I'm hosting.

Comment: The viewport meta tag doesn't use the colon character for values, use the equals sign instead. Eg. `<meta type="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`